# .htaccess clean urls without trailing slashes?

Tags: .htaccess

My site has links that ent to .html or .php.
I would like to have clean urls without trailing slash at the end.
With

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

I have clean urls but with trailing slash at the end. Whatever I tried had no success..
Thank you!

Comment: Post some examples of URLs you try and what they rewrite to.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a trailing slash use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /example/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Options is required by Many Hosting

```
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

If you need to add any other file for instance .txt just add this

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.txt [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replies!
This works perfectly:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Thanks a lot!